# Good explanation of cascade (ON DELETE/UPDATE) behavior

Tags: mysql, foreign-key

I don't design schemas everyday, but when I do, I try to setup cascade updates/deletes correctly to make administration easier. I understand how cascades work, but I can never remember which table is which.

For example, if I have two tables - `Parent` and `Child` - with a foreign key on `Child` that references `Parent` and has `ON DELETE CASCADE`, which records trigger a cascade and which records get deleted by the cascade? My first guess would be the `Child` records get deleted when `Parent` records are deleted, since `Child` records depend on `Parent` records, but the `ON DELETE` is ambiguous; it could mean delete the `Parent` record when the `Child` record is deleted, or it could mean delete the `Child` record when the `Parent` is deleted. So which is it?

I wish the syntax was `ON PARENT DELETE, CASCADE`, `ON FOREIGN DELETE, CASCADE` or something similar to remove the ambiguity. Does anyone have any mnemonics for remembering this?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/38388423/562769

Answer (score 229, accepted):

If you like the **`Parent`** and **`Child`** terms and you feel they are easy to be remembered, you may like the translation of `ON DELETE CASCADE` to **`Leave No Orphans!`**

Which means that when a `Parent` row is deleted (killed), no orphan row should stay alive in the `Child` table. All children of the parent row are killed (deleted), too. If any of these children has grandchildren (in another table through another foreign key) and there is `ON DELETE CASCADE` defined, these should be killed, too (and all descendants, as long as there is a cascade effect defined.)

The `FOREIGN KEY` constraint itself could also be described as **`Allow No Orphans!`** (in the first place). No `Child` should ever be allowed (written) in the child table if it hasn't a `Parent` (a row in the parent table).

For consistency, the `ON DELETE RESTRICT` can be translated to the (less aggresive) **`You Can't Kill Parents!`** Only childless rows can be killed (deleted.)

Comment: I feel something is still missing in the analogy. Can't a child have more than one parent? In this case will killing one parent make the child an orphan?

Comment: @Jus12 No, foreign key constraints work with 1 parent only. It's not a good analogy regarding this aspect.

Comment: @ypercube: Is this not allowed? `Order(custID, itemID, orderID)` where `custID` refers to a primary key in `Customers` table and `itemID` refers to a primary key in `Items` table. Won't `Order` have two parents?

Comment: @Jus12 That is allowed of course but it would be 2 foreign key constraints. Then every child (order) would have a parent (customer) and a parent (item). The behaviours of the 2 FKs might differ though. (So, for example, it could be that killing customers would kill all their (orders) children but killing items would not kill their orders.)

Comment: The parent analogy can still work if we don't say "orphan". If there are two references to two separate parents on a child entry, this can still be seen as a child of a divorced couple.

Restrict: "I won't let you kill my mom"
Cascade: "If you kill my dad, I will also die"

Comment: @ChristopherMcGowan  This analogy does explain better but you made it very funny :-D

Comment: I don't like word "kill" here. I prefer to say "euthanize" or "annihilate", much more professional. And `On Delete Leave No Witnesses`

Answer (score 49):

> For example, if I have two tables - Parent and Child - where Child
>   records are owned by Parent records, which table needs the ON DELETE
>   CASCADE?

ON DELETE CASCADE is an optional clause in a foreign key declaration. So it goes *with* the foreign key declaration. (Meaning, in the "child" table.)

> ...it could mean delete the Parent record when the Child record is
>   deleted, or it could mean delete the Child record when the Parent is
>   deleted. So which is it?

One way to interpret a foreign key declaration is, "All valid values for this column come from 'that_column' in 'that_table'." When you delete a row in the "child" table, nobody cares. It doesn't affect data integrity.

When you delete a row from the "parent" table--from "that_table"--you remove a valid value from the possible values for the "child" table. To maintain data integrity, you have to do *something* to the "child" table. Cascading deletes is one thing you can do.

---

Chapter and verse, from [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html).

> Restricting and cascading deletes are the two most common options.
>   RESTRICT prevents deletion of a referenced row. NO ACTION means that
>   if any referencing rows still exist when the constraint is checked, an
>   error is raised; this is the default behavior if you do not specify
>   anything. (The essential difference between these two choices is that
>   NO ACTION allows the check to be deferred until later in the
>   transaction, whereas RESTRICT does not.) CASCADE specifies that when a
>   referenced row is deleted, row(s) referencing it should be
>   automatically deleted as well. There are two other options: SET NULL
>   and SET DEFAULT. These cause the referencing column(s) in the
>   referencing row(s) to be set to nulls or their default values,
>   respectively, when the referenced row is deleted. Note that these do
>   not excuse you from observing any constraints. For example, if an
>   action specifies SET DEFAULT but the default value would not satisfy
>   the foreign key constraint, the operation will fail.

Comment: thanks but what other things can you do?

Comment: @leeCoder: Updated answer with references to the docs.

Answer (score 19):

## SQL:2011 Spec

There are five options for `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE` that can apply to the `FOREIGN KEY`. These are called `<referential actions>`, directly from the SQL:2011 spec

> - `ON DELETE CASCADE`: if a row of the referenced table is deleted, then all matching rows in the referencing table are deleted.
> - `ON DELETE SET NULL`: if a row of the referenced table is deleted, then all referencing columns in all matching rows of the referencing table to be set to null.
> - `ON DELETE SET DEFAULT`: if a row of the referenced table is deleted, then all referencing columns in all matching rows of the referencing table to be set to the column’s default value.
> - `ON DELETE RESTRICT`: it is prohibited to delete a row of the referenced table if that row has any matching rows in the referencing table.
> - `ON DELETE NO ACTION` **(the default)**: there is no referential delete action; the referential constraint only specifies a constraint check.

The foreign key establishes the dependent relationship. The `<referential action>` determines what happens when the relationship is dissolved.

### Example / Metaphor / Explanation

For this example, we will accept the common model of society and economy: where every `business` is a company that maintains a relationship to the `bourgeoisie` through a `fatcat_owner`.

```
CREATE TABLE bourgeoisie(
  fatcat_owner varchar(100) PRIMARY KEY
);
INSERT INTO bourgeoisie(fatcat_owner) VALUES
  ( 'Koch Brothers' );

CREATE TABLE business (
  name         varchar(100),
  fatcat_owner varchar(100) REFERENCES bourgeoisie
);
INSERT INTO business(name, fatcat_owner)
  VALUES ('Georgia-Pacific', 'Koch Brothers');
```

If all `business`es are directly affected by `bourgeoisie` by way of their `fatcat_owner` then what do you do after the workers' revolution when that you purge the `fatcat_owner`s and have a classless society?

```
-- Viva la revolución 
BEGIN;
  DELETE FROM bourgeoisie;
END;
```

You have a few options here,

- Stop the revolution. In SQL parlance, `RESTRICT`. Some people believe this is the lesser evil, but they're usually wrong.
- Allow it to go on. If so when the revolution happens SQL gives you four options,

  - `SET NULL` -- leave it blank. Who knows, maybe capitalism is restored the `bourgeoisie` comes up and oligarchs fill the roll of the `fatcat_owners`. Important note, the column must be `NULLABLE` (not `NOT NULL`) or this can never happen.
  - `SET DEFAULT` -- perhaps you had a `DEFAULT` that handled this? A
    `DEFAULT` can call a function. Maybe your schema is revolution-ready, already.
  - `CASCADE` -- there is no damage control. If the `bourgeoisie` goes, so does the `business`. If a business *must* have a `fatcat_owner`, then sometimes it makes more sense to lose the data rather than have a non-business in a `business` table.
  - `NO ACTION` -- this is essentially a method of delaying the check, in MySQL it's no different than `RESTRICT`, but in PostgreSQL, you'd be able to do

    ```
        -- Not a real revolution.
        -- requires constraint be DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED
        BEGIN;
          SET CONSTRAINTS ALL DEFERRED;
          DELETE FROM bourgeoisie;
          INSERT INTO bourgeoisie VALUES ( 'Putin' );
          UPDATE business SET fatcat_owner = 'Putin';
        END;
    ```

    In such a system, the constraint is validated only before the transaction commits. This may result in stopping the revolution, but you can recover in the transaction -- for some degree of "recover."

Comment: Does `referenced` table means parent table and `referencing` table means child table?

Comment: @sg552 Yes, you understood it correctly.

Answer (score 6):

A simple mnemonic would be

**ON DELETE of parent CASCADE [by deleting] here**

That tells you which deletes (deletes of the parent) get cascaded, where the *ON DELETE CASCADE* statement goes (on the child), and what gets deleted (the child).

Answer (score 1):

Just remember: **Relational databases are all about consistency**. They want to ensure the data is consistent all the time.

[image]

If you have an `Author` table and a `Book` table, the `Book` table might have an `author_id`. Assume the `author_id` is set to `on_delete=CASCADE`.

The DB will become active when an author is deleted. When an author is deleted, the Book table could reference an ID that does no longer exist. Meaning that a deletion of an Author might need a "cascading" deletion of a book.

Answer (score -3):

well, perhaps we can rationalize the syntax. Let's take a Python example:

```
class Parent(self):
    # define parent's fields

class Child(self):    
    # define child's fields
    parent_pk_is_childs_foreign_key = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

what this line says is on_delete of the Parent (which is accidentally mentioned in the statement), please cascade the deletion onto the child. That is why the CASCADE statement is defined at the child level, it marks those children that need to be deleted

For example if you had another class

```
class GrownUpChild(self):    
        # define grown up child's fields
        parent_pk_is_childs_foreign_key = models.ForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

this structure would clearly show which of the children need to be removed (Child) and which are to stay (GrownUpChild) albeit orphaned

[Edit: Given the context of the discussion, specifically in cases of on_delete=models.CASCADE etc, ] in fact it is often a desired behavior to leave children of a deleted parent, due to auditing and reporting reasons, as well as recovering accidental deletions. [ of course enterprise level software will be built around such behavior and will flag deleted records as deleted=1 instead of actually deleting them and also will not include them in any queries for the front end, minus some specially designed reports. In addition it will have a function of purging the deleted==1 records from the database, which will usually be executed by the UI administrator, often avoiding any involvement from the database administrator's side.]

Comment: _'In fact it is often a desired behavior to leave children of a deleted parent, due to auditing and reporting reasons, as well as recovering accidental deletions'_ - that would be disastrous in a (sane) database.

Comment: @dezso thanks for your input. However, multiple enterprise level CRM systems do exactly that.

Comment: you sound like a savvy database admin :) I can totally hear your point. The software I mentioned above that does it, actually has a function to remove those deleted = 1 manually so it is up to the admin of the app to make this call. Normally database administrator is not even involved in maintaining this aspect. And besides, the entire software's database class is built around the concept, so it always checks for deleted flag in crud operations

Comment: Yes, that is a known and sane pattern - but then you should possibly change the wording above to reflect this.